# Вызвать winapi функцию из kernel32

Tags: winapi, d

Не нашел, как вызвать функцию QueryPerformanceCounter. Пробовал так. Выдает ошибки, не знает, что такое BOOL и LARGE_INTEGER.

```
import core.sys.windows.windows;
import core.sys.windows.w32api;
import core.sys.windows.winbase;
pragma(lib, "kernel32");
extern (Windows)
{
    BOOL QueryPerformanceCounter(LARGE_INTEGER *lpPerformanceCount);
}
void main()
{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import core.sys.windows.winbase;
import core.sys.windows.windef;
import core.sys.windows.windows : QueryPerformanceCounter, QueryPerformanceFrequency;

void main()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER start, finish, freq;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
    //any long function
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&finish);
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
}
```